# Hardware for USSD/SMS applications testing

Tags: sms, gsm, modem, ussd, smslib

We are looking for hardware having functionality of usual GSM-modem to automate the USSD/SMS applications for the set of 8 SIM-cards. The hardware should understand basic AT commands to be sent via java smslib, used in code running on CI server. The general purpose is to test USSD/SMS applications (i.e. asserting the sms and ussd responces) for SIM-cards belonging to different regional platforms, but with the same workflow. We already have tried to do it for a single SIM-card in one modem, now we'd like to avoid manual replacing of the SIM cards. Also, it would be perfect if this solution could be also applied for IVR services testing in future.

The first idea is to use Smslib + USB hub + 8 GSM modem, but the total cost will be ~ 8* 30$. 
Some GSM-gates we have found are 2300$, and they doesn't support USSD.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.made-in-china.com/showroom/lindamodem/product-detailfoVQbuOYHXcn/China-16-Sim-Cards-Multi-port-Modem-Pool-GSM-GPRS-SimBox.html

it seems that such kind of hardware exists, but it still unclear, is it possible to send both sms and ussd with this hardware. Unfortunatetly, nobody answers on that site.

Comment: Unfortunately still nothing known about their USSD-support.

Comment: Did you find alternative methods of approaching the situation? I'm in the same position, and any assistance would be much appreciated.